# Will using a hard drive with the MBR virus cause the main system to be infected?

Tags: virus, boot

If I have an old hard drive and assume it has an MBR virus.
If I install it on my computer using a SATA cable as the D drive to store data, will my system drive (C drive) be affected by the MBR virus?

Answer (score 1):

An MBR virus needs to be executed to become active. If this second drive is not a system boot drive, this will never happen and you're safe. MBR is executed [on boot] only if the disk is the default boot device in the system.

Out of an abundance of precaution I'd still recommend checking the entire drive using a strong antivirus of your choice.

You could consult with [www.av-comparatives.org](http://www.av-comparatives.org) which publishes great overviews of AVs.